# Chaining sshuttle commands over two hops

Tags: ssh, vpn, routing, ssh-tunnel

I have the following scenario:

- Host A: Mi machine
- Host B: Server - 192.168.1.1
- Host C: Hop node - 192.168.2.1
- Network N: 192.168.3.0/24

Using sshuttle what's the best way to forward and be able to reach machines of network N (192.168.3.0/24) from Machine A, passing thru B and C?

I can actually run:

```
sshuttle -r root@192.168.1.1 -v 192.168.3.0/24 &
ssh root@192.168.1.1
sshuttle -r root@$192.168.2.1 -v 192.168.3.0/24 &
```

If I open in the browser for example http://192.168.3.5 from Machine A I'm receiving the TCP packages in the destination node, but not getting routed correctly the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ProxyCommand` like for every other multi-hop setup. Create a file `~/.ssh/config` with

```
Host B
  Hostname 192.168.1.1
  User root
Host C
  Hostname 192.168.2.1
  User root
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B
```

Then just connect using sshuttle:

```
sshuttle -r C -v 192.168.3.0/24 &
```

Comment: I tried also using ProxyCommand but wasn't making the jump to the other node.
Commenting the ProxyCommand line allows to forward the traffic to the host B, but then, if using ProxyCommand the connection hangs when routing to C.

Comment: Remember that A can only see B can only see C can only see 192.168.3.0/24

Comment: So then it is the other way then you described (A -> B -> C). Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sshuttle -r user@targetMachine -e 'ssh -J jumpHost1,jumpHost2' <forwardedNetwork>
```